# Combobox does not strech automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a grid that looks like follow:

```
 <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20,50,10,10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

And inside the grid, I place a combobox:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="28" VerticalAlignment="Center"
      VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="10,0,0,0"
      SelectedItem="{Binding Language, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Languages, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="10,0,0,0">
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28" />
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

My problem is, that the combobox does not automatically fit the whole height of grid as you can see here:
[image]

In contrast, the TextBox always fit the whole size of grid. How can I customize, that ComboBox auto fit to grid size?

Comment: Have you tried `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried `ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="28" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` and it does not work as expected.

Comment: I just tried your code, its shows me stretch combobox, there is no issue at all. I think some predefined styleset you have applied on combobox

Comment: Have you tried using this xaml yourself in a fresh clean wpf sample app in an attempt to try to isolate your problem?

Comment: I am using infragistics theme manager, that's the reason why combobox does not fit the grid.